# How can I do a "where in" type query using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I perform a where-in type query using ember-data?

Say I have a list of tags - how can I use the store to query the API to get all relevant records where they have one of the tags present?

Something like this:

```
 return this.store.find('tags', {
            name: {
                "in": ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't built in support for something like that. And, I don't think its needed.

The result that you are after can be obtained in two steps.

```
return this.store.find('posts'); // I guess its a blog
```

and then in your controller you use a computed property

```
filteredPosts: function('model', function() {
  var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];
  return this.get('model').filter(function(post) {
    if ( /* post has one of tags */ ) {
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

**Update:** What if there are tens of thousands of tags?!

Amother option is to send a list of tags as a single argument to the back end. You'll have to do a bit of data processing before sending a request and before querying.

```
return this.store.find('tags', {
  tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'].join(', ')
})
```

In your API you'll know that the `tags` argument needs to be converted into an array before querying the DB.

So, this is better because you avoid the very expensive nested loop caused by the use of `filter`. (expensive !== bad, it has its benefits)

It is a concern to think that there will be tens of thousands of tags, if those are going to be available in your Ember app they'll have a big memory footprint and maybe something much more advanced is needed in terms of app design.

Comment: What if there are tens of thousands of tags?!

Comment: cheers @givanse :) i had a sneaking suspicion it would be something like this... starting to fall out of love with ember-data :/